# jQuery - Restricting input to numbers and a single decimal and only two decimal points

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text input on my site and I want to restrict it to only numbers and a maximum of two decimal points. I have the number restriction working but can't figure out how to adapt it to only allow two decimal points:

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var $input = $(this),
        val = $(this).val();

    if(isNaN(val)){
        val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
        if(val.split('.').length > 2) 
            val = val.replace(/\.+$/,'');
    }
    $input.val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: After you split the string, take the fractional part and find it's length

Comment: check at this question the valid answer, maybe it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307743/limit-numbers-before-and-after-decimal-point-on-input-number   if not try with val.ToFixed(2)